# Setting custom RGB color in drawing class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, colors, drawrect

In the below simplified drawing function, I am able to set the alpha of a drawing stroke.

I have a custom color with RGB values, for example Red = 0.25, Green = 0.5, Blue = 0.75.

How do I set a custom RGB stroke color in the drawing function similar to setting the alpha?

Is it also possible to set a stroke color together with setting the stroke alpha in a single statement?

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

strokeColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).setStroke()
path?.stroke()

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to set the color try this:

```
var Color = UIColor(red: 200.0/255.0, green: 16.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

also a very useful tool/ website for converting the colors into useful Swift code:

https://www.ralfebert.de/snippets/ios/swift-uicolor-picker/

**Edit:**

```
self.button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.28, blue:0.28, alpha:1.0), forState: .Normal)
```

or if you want a cleaner solution:

```
var myColor = UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.28, blue:0.28, alpha:1.0)
self.button.setTitleColor(myColor, forState: .Normal)
```